# Assigned a type based on a extended type is not processed correctly

Tags: typescript

EASY explanation at the end :

I have the following case, a type looking like this :

```
type ItemType<Advanced> = Advanced extends true
  ? BrandsListQuery['brands']['items'][0]
  : MinimalBrandsListQuery['brands']['items'][0];
```

`Advanced` is passed to a function like this

```
const BrandSelectGn = <
  Advanced extends boolean = false
>() = {}
```

Now the issue I have is in the code I am trying to map a return type to one or the other type,

Saying  `BrandsListQuery['brands']['items'][0]`  and `MinimalBrandsListQuery['brands']['items'][0]` have basically the same format, just the `items` are different (I do this to have type completion in the `useLoadOptions` method

```
interface RequiredResponse<I> {
  [key: string]: {
    total: number;
    items: readonly I[];
  };
}


export const useLoadOptions = <
  I,
  LQ extends RequiredResponse<I>,
>({})


  const { loadOptions } = useLoadOptions<
    ItemType<Advanced>,
    Advanced extends true ? BrandsListQuery : MinimalBrandsListQuery,
  >({
```

but typescript do not recognized that essentially what I am saying is its the same structure and based on  `Advanced` it is one or the other

TLDR:
Now this might be confusing, so I put a simplified playground :
[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmgQWQbwFDLKQDOYAXLgYUQPZhwA2FIArgLYBG0A3FYcJDbEKmKFDgBPADw4BENgBUJABwiYKpKKADmAXwB8vQrt668eUJFiIU6KwCFKhEuSfUwdRs3ZcoR6nJCImKSMoFKqvYaYFogeoZUJnhmeGAqtoIREFKYACYAbnAgSLn6yAC8yHmFxRC5yBAAHpAgucREUCwoAPxoGFCYANoA5C7DALojgcQTgwAM48gUdtD2I2OTw9OzC7wW-fBIyABKEACOLMBQdafEyjQgxNmoZfjOEKQUb+6eTMisnB4fGQ02Wg3G-iSKSa9ygYGQCAepGQLCeABkaHBcgB5ZRgYBIirIKRUVAAGioaIAig1mhBWu1ThcrjcPvdHs99BT9AAKACUFVeKTwiMe8Ny8hoADEWMUiTkCkUSrSWm1kBwaDQGBAikSNVqdSBeQLyq9gaiIBisbj8UiSdQ0Jl0gqaiUucDqkq6ir6WqYl1kL0VgMln0HGTkAB6SNEAAWwHaDFAKGIsZoLAY9S4CJoYggCDAEeAMCqitq9Saqva-ogEbAsfpjvkWRdXtKIPawewEAYTxB8PallWVGNySAA)

```
interface InterA {
  test: {
    total: number;
    items: Array<{itemTypeA: string}>;
  };
}

interface InterB {
  test: {
    total: number;
    items: Array<{itemTypeB: string}>;
  };
}

type ItemType<Advanced> = Advanced extends true ? InterA['test']['items'][0] : InterB['test']['items'][0];

interface RequiredResponse<I> {
  test: {
    total: number;
    items: I[];
  };
}

export const useLoadOptions = <
  I,
  LQ extends RequiredResponse<I>,
>() => {}


const demoFunc = <Advanced extends boolean = boolean>() => {
    useLoadOptions<
    ItemType<Advanced>,
    Advanced extends true ? InterA : InterB, // this line should be correct, if Advanced extends true, then ItemType<Advanced> is InterA else it s interB
  >()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: `ItemType` should be:

```
type ItemType<Advanced> = 
  (Advanced extends true ? InterA : InterB)['test']['items'][0];
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmgQWQbwFDLKQDOYAXLgYUQPZhwA2FIArgLYBG0A3FYcJDbEKmKFDgBPADw4BENgBUJABwiYKpKKADmAXwB8vQrt668eUJFiIU6KwCFKhEuSfUwdRs3ZcoR6nJCImKSMoFKqvYaYFogeoZUJnhmeGAqtoIREFKYACYAbnAgSLn6yAC8yAAUeYXFELnIEAAekCC5xERQLCgA-GgYUNgUdtD2AJQA2gDkLtMAujOBxAuTAAzzvBaD8EjIAEoQAI4swFANh8TKNCDE2ahl+M4QpBRP7p5MyKycPHzIyxGk02iVM5ha1ygYGQCBupGQLDuABkaHBcgB5ZRgYBwirIKRUVAAGioSIAik1WhB2p1DiczhcXtdbvd9CT9FVxhVHik8LDbtDcvIaAAxFjFPE5ApFEqUtodZAcGg0BgQIp4pUqtUgDlc8qPf6IiAotGY7FwgnUNCZdJSuolNn-Woyhpy6kKmI9ZD9UZDZAjQaOAD0QaIAAtgJ0GKAUMQwzQWAxGlwYTQxBAEGAiQCYMhnfVGi15Z1PRBs2Aw9TrfIsnaXaUAZ1fdgIAw7gDoZ1LGMqLrkuYgwAqQcEQfIEVp1NsZRwLTEG7ZhCVhAAa3DkeQCbAADpkAB1FAriAQZTIAAGqBtqgATGfwygAO6SDvIJ-Ebej5AAWn3lZAeelAtG2QdVxRXEAaAff9tGpaBgAQIh0hAqBtHYaksyafIqwfAQwzdGlFWVVV1X5TQ4EsbMBGmBgGGQUhgBopoxDTD9kDHH97BYaEHz-Dtpk6OBU2Kc5IAREAcX-M80lUAD7VdSpNWIkBuGQEMmnpfJdw8ZAACJS2QAAfZB4DbCAdLEiSz3LStkFySMYmADguOALCvxoLCoC-cUJMVCAwzgfIcSgYCHO0GDzlybNoCgSdtBuMtkGuSxEpirDclYwcg1SJDLxrdJrzrAsykqfNZSLd0S26PoBisTAZjmRZpmWVYNn9Gqxnql4wFWJrBBWRYNi2UjBWFMVimvSVStdcqCMU7UNSI7VdW5NxCCNE0MSxCTiEtahcsUfLCodEkrSmwsqQI-SfUGYZ2qgYNQ2itMAEJkEAGXJe05fs+ThEa2FFcUEAAZjxTkVveZwkLOhatSKfw1uRVFNvNW5dsIfasgKs7HVOwCyouj0qu9O7bt9B7NzXQBQck+8ZkiAA)

I don't have authoritative explanation for this, and probably it's just implementation defined behavior that isn't documented anywhere. I never really understand how generic type argument is further interpreted within function body.

But my personal mind model about this mess, is to view it as Schrodinger's cat.

Conditional type over an undetermined generic type argument, is like an unobserved superposition of **both-dead-and-alive** state. Intellisense tooltip will just show sth like `Advanced extends true ? InterA : InterB` as a whole, without further interpretation.

Accessing this superposition entity by adding `(...)["some_key"]` behind it, is like you observe it, and it'll collapse into **either-dead-or-alive** state. Intellisense tooltip will try its best effort to interpret the conditional type as distributive over union somehow, and show sth like `A | B`.

I believe this behavior is partly addressed in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

> When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type.

But it doesn't concretely state "when" exactly will it "act". It seems to me accessing the thing with a key triggers the action.

For comparison, check this out. We keep `ItemType2` the way it was.

- When `Advanced` is an undetermined generic type argument, even with `extends boolean` constraint, it'll still error.
- But when it's a concrete union `type Advanced = boolean; // equiv. to "true | false" union`, the distributive-over-union behavior is triggered, error gone, point proved.

```
type ItemType2<Advanced> = Advanced extends true ? InterA['test']['items'][0] : InterB['test']['items'][0];

const demoFunc2 = <Advanced extends boolean = boolean>() => {
    useLoadOptions<
    ItemType2<Advanced>,
    Advanced extends true ? InterA : InterB // error! ❌
  >()
}

const demoFunc3 = () => {
    type Advanced = boolean;
    useLoadOptions<
    ItemType2<Advanced>,
    Advanced extends true ? InterA : InterB // ok ✅
  >()
}
```

Comment: wow I needed to read this three times xD